# using iframe in laravel blade view

Tags: laravel

I have a web site with a page having web form to enter data into mysql database.
Now requirement has changed and I need to convert the whole web site to laravel.

In current web page there is index.php which has a menu strip and a iframe. on clicking a menu item the linked page is opened in the Iframe.
Now How to achieve the same flexiblity using Laravel.

How to redirect/route the web form in the iframe.

Below is the index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/header.js"></script>
    <link href="css/stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="menustrip">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" onclick="OpenForm('register.php');">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php" onclick="OpenForm('search.php');">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe" style="position:fixed;top:62px; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" >
        <iframe name="main" id="main" src="" frameborder="0" width="99%" height="95%" align="left"><FONT FACE=ARIAL SIZE=3 COLOR="RED">Your Browser doesn't Support Required Component.</FONT></iframe>
    </div>    

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show your code for index

Comment: its an old approach to use template. i would suggest you not you use this approach with laravel. instead use blade template technique.  see doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade

Comment: @reza do i have to use in every blade view to get my menu?

Comment: In every blade file you will extend main template. Your main template will almost same as shown index.html file

Answer (score 4):

You can use iframe in Laravel blade like this.

This is for local .html file(file in public dir)

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to('/')}}/your file path here" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

This is for the online url

```
<iframe src="http://www.onlineicttutor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pdf-at-iframe.pdf" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `OpenForm()` functions just sets the src of the iframe to the register.php in first case and to search.php so instead of going to `register.php` or `search.php` you define these at the route file. 
in Route.php define the `register`
Ex:

```
Route::get('register', function () {
//code to go here or use controllers
return view('register');
});
```

Then just set the src of the iframe to register and you will have the same approach as your site in core PHP.

Comment: but for that i have to open the index.php blade view which has the menu item, else above code will open the Register blade view without the menus.

Comment: I think that you are not into laravel blade templating. Now you must work with blade templates and laravel routing or there is no sense of using laravel.